# Discord Bot for kicking a specific user determined in the code by id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So this is the code but when I run the code I get a strange error.
By this code, I want to be able to kick my friend Luke just by writing !kick in discord. I am pretty new to javaScript and I think I might have chosen a pretty difficult project but in theory, it should work but I can't think of a reason that I get a null value for member.kick when where it says USERID I enter the specific id from devDiscord.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const prefix = '!';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ON');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if (command === "kick") {
//      client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
        let member = message.guild.member(USEDID);
        member.kick();
        kickd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        if (kickd == 1) {
            member.kick();
            message.channel.send("USER KICK");
            return;
        } else {
            message.channel.send("USER NOT KICK");
            return;
        }
    }
});
 
client.login('TOKEN');
```

```html
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\BOT DISCORD\main.js:31
        member.kick();
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'kick' of null
```

Comment: what is the value of member, it seems that the function kick isnt a prototype of member

Answer (score 0):

`kickd`, `USEDID` are undefined.

The error is caused by the `member` variable returning null because `USEDID` is not defined. Try entering a test id and see if it works.

I would collect the user id by a `message.mentions.users.first()` e.g.

```js
let userID = message.mentions.users.first().id;
//then run the guildMember get method
let member = message.guild.member(userID);

member.kick(); //this should now kick the member
```